# Parallax backgrounds not taking up full 'page' area

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parallax, smooth-scrolling

I am using [StickyPanel](https://code.google.com/p/sticky-panel/), [Smooth-Scroll](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll) and [Scrolly](http://lab.victorcoulon.fr/javascript/scrolly/), and I need fixed (content moves over it) backgrounds on the **even** 'pages', and a parallax background (content & background move separate to each other) on the *odd* 'pages'. So my 'pages' go **even**, *odd*, **even**, *odd*, **even**. The 'pages' are 5 divs, one under the other, and each div is set to the width & height of the browser window, to make a one page website.

The problem I am having is that on 'pages' 2 & 4 with the parallax backgrounds, the background is mispositioned. By inspecting the element, I found that the background-position set by *Scrolly* is so far off, the background images don't even show up. *Scrolly* gives you two attributes to set on the element with the scrolling background:

```
<div data-velocity=".3" data-fit="1000">
```

These allow you to set the speed of the Parallax element and set the relative background position respectively. I have found that when I adjust the backgrounds using the data-fit attribute, it will never be in the right place, because the 'page' and thus the background height are relative to the browser window.

**I need the background to always be covering the div, i.e. if the background-image was an image with no transparency, then the background-color of the divs would never show.**

I think possibly setting the background to ~10% more than the browser window could help, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8742d/embedded/result/), although for some reason the background image won't show on 'page' 5. I also set the background image to a placeholder, and set the divs to have random background colours, for ease whilst in development.

This has been a hard problem to explain, so I may not have thoroughly conveyed my point. If I think of a better way to explain the problem, I will update my post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this was a simple one, finally figured it out though. I was half way through using JS to get the page height, get 130% of the page height and then set the background image css as that, when I realised I can just set it in CSS.... So I set the background-size to 100% 130%, and then it was just a case of perfecting it with the data-fit attribute. It's close enough for my liking now anyway.

```
background-size: 100% 130%;
```

[jsFiddle for those interested](http://jsfiddle.net/8742d/4/)